# Is it possible to get the ID of the div / img when double click on an image using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now I have an html page that display image. Notice that the div only contain 1 image file:

```
<div="div_1"><img id = "img_1" src = '....' /></div>
```

What I would like to implement is when user double click on the div , through jquery/ js to get the "div_1" or "img_1" . In better way, get the "1" . Is it possible to implement / any function can help to achieve that?

Thanks

**Updated:**

The current Html code is like that

```
<div class="turn-page-wrapper" page="2" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 28.5px; height: 37px; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 6;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: auto; width: 47px; height: 47px;">
<div id="div_2" class="turn-page p2" style="width: 28.5px; height: 37px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: auto; right: auto;">
<img id="img_2" src="demo/medium/Web081112_P002_medium.jpg" alt="flip book">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It seems my case is not that straight forward, when i use `var id = $(this).attr("id");` it return page as result. If my case don't allow me to get the attribute of page,  the id of image, then it means i can not get the actual ID of individual image? thanks

**Most Updated ( 1 flaw left only!)**

```
$("div.turn-page").dblclick(function() {
var id = this.id;
num = id.split("_")[1];
alert (num);
});
```

Currently I am using this to get the id , however for the last result (not turn-able) when i double click it do not response or do anything. But it should be work since the class there is turn-page p7 ?

```
   <div class="turn-page-wrapper" page="7" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 609.5922459893047px; height: 793px; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 6;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: auto; width: 1000px; height: 1000px;">
    <div id="div_7" class="turn-page p7" style="width: 609.5922459893047px; height: 793px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: auto; right: auto;">
    <img id="img_7" src="demo/medium/Web081112_P007_medium.jpg" alt="flip book">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 610px; height: 793px;">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is very, very possible. What have you tried so far? --->

Comment: I have tried to set the <div> as a button or something, when onclicked it trigger the function that can get img path?

Comment: updated question . Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("div").dblclick(function() {
    var id = this.id,
        num = id.split("_")[1],
        imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");

    // do something with the id, the number, or the image src
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LGwK7/

This will bind a double-click handler to *all* div elements, so you might want to add a common class to just the ones you care about and bind to those. (I'm assuming it doesn't make sense to bind by id because you asked how to get the id of the clicked one.)

Note that your html has an error: `<div="div_1"...`, should be `<div id="div_1"...`

Comment: @VIDesignz - I often see completely correct answers downvoted for no apparent reason, so I don't worry when it happens to me. I assume in a lot of cases the downvoter _can't_ explain why...

Comment: Just haters I guess...ughh

Comment: Yeah - where were they earlier when I needed a few downvotes to take my reputation down to 36363? By the way, thanks for the upvote @VIDesignz.

Comment: @user782104 - For your updated html you probably want to use `$("div.turn-page").dblclick(...` as per what I said in my answer about using a class so that you don't bind to _all_ divs.

Comment: Your updated code works in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/MV9xd/ so perhaps you have some other code that breaks it.

Comment: @nnnnnn this is off topic, but I think I am losing my mind... Does $(document).load(); actually work? I swear it did but now it seems it doesn't...

Comment: @VIDesignz - I've never tried `$(document).load()`. If you're trying to attach an event handler try `$(window).load()` instead (assuming `$(document).ready()` doesn't suit your purpose). If you're trying to use the Ajax `.load()` method I'm not sure what happens if you try to use it on the `document` but I wouldn't think it a good plan.

Comment: @VIDesignz I don't think so. This is from the jQuery API docs for the `load` method: "This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object." Nothing about `document`, so I think it wouldn't. Unless you mean the other purpose of `load` to use AJAX...

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you man...I have seen it around and never second guessed it, it was only when I implemented it that I realized it didn't work.  I thought it was because I upgraded my jquery to 1.8

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("div_1").children[0].id
```

This will return the id of the first child of the "div_1" div

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps given that the OP already has an id-allocation scheme that gives parallel ids to the images and their containing divs. He or she wants to get the id of a _clicked_ element...

Comment: He wanted the id of either the div or img tag. And it´s easy to modify this code to get the id of the div

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var divId;

$('div').dblclick(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    divId = $(this).prop('id');
});
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe the double click could trigger viewing the image in a browser light box. It may not be needed though :)

Comment: `$(this).prop("id")` is too much jQuery. Just do `this.id`

Comment: Good point @IHateLazy - I'm embarrassed to say I did the same thing in my own answer (now updated) even though I often point out the same thing to others. Oops.

Comment: @IHateLazy I can respect that...jquery has erased my javascript memory! :o

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yeah, it's not the worst  pattern one can adopt. Just needlessly heavy and complex.